# ProcessBuilder command argument

Tags: java, linux, processbuilder

(Sorry for my english I'm french) I'm creating a tiny Java IDE for my school project, but I'm facing a problem with running classes under Linux (I'm using Debian 7.3), no problem with Win 8.1

I'm using ProcessBuilder class to execute the java bin with some arguments, wich are args and projectOut

args = the class we want to run

projectOut = the absolute project path+"/out"

```
package com.esgi.honeycode;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CustomRun {

public static void run(String args, final String projectOut) throws IOException {

    System.out.flush();


    if (args != null && projectOut != null) {

        //SEPARATOR is a const for the file separator
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-classpath", "\"" + System.getProperty("java.class.path") + System.getProperty("path.separator") + projectOut + PropertiesShared.SEPARATOR + "out\"", args);
        System.out.println(builder.command());

        builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        final Process process = builder.start();


        Thread outThread = new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {

                    String line;
                    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()))) {
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            System.out.println(line);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };


        Thread inThread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
                //Need to control in before !!

                while (true) {
                    String input = s.nextLine();

                    try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream()))) {
                        pw.write(input);
                        pw.flush();
                    }

                }
            }

        };

        outThread.start();
        inThread.start();

    }

}

}
```

Testing with a simple class :

```
public class MyClass{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("TESTESTE");
}
}
```

the class is stored in : /home/m3te0r/HoneyCodeProjects/untitledaaa/out

And if I try to run the class, I get this output, with the command print :

[java, -classpath, "/home/m3te0r/Bureau/HoneyCode.jar:/home/m3te0r/HoneyCodeProjects/untitledaaa/out", MyClass]

Error: Could not find or load main class MyClass

Like I said, there is no problem under Win 8.1 and it also works when I run the same command in a terminal.

EDIT FOR THE ANSWER ():

Ok, so I figured out what was wrong.
I just removed the escaped double quotes fot the classpath and it worked.

I was thinking there would be a problem with spaced dir names or files, but there is not.

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-classpath", System.getProperty("java.class.path") + System.getProperty("path.separator") + projectOut + PropertiesShared.SEPARATOR + "out", args);
```

Comment: Is the class file *definitely* in that directory? If you run the same command from a shell, what happens?

Comment: Is it a file permission issue? Are you running the IDE under the same user that you are running the command in the terminal?

Comment: Yes, the class is definitly in the out dir, and if I run the command from a shell I get the good output : TESTESTE

Comment: @Matt I don't think it's a file permisssion issue, i'm able to save/edit/compile java sources with this IDE, and yes, I'm running the IDE and the command with the same user.